# How about a [date-manipulation] tag or redefine the [date] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few questions here are about date/time manipulation like:

- [Get the date of last month's last day in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223543)
- [linux + add X days to date and get new virtual date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49053)
- [How to compare two dates in a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84381)
- [Next day of the user entered date - date +1 day](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97913)
- the date for last Monday?
- the number of seconds between two dates?
- ...

I couldn't find a tag for that. Should we make one? What shall it be? `date-manipulation`, `date-calculation`, `time-calculation`?

Some of those questions above are tagged [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date). At the moment, the description of that tag is for the `date` utility. Except for the GNU implementation, that utility's date manipulation capabilities are very limited. Maybe the [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) tag could be changed to mean anything date/time related (including the POSIX `date` utility).

Comment: Normally those questions are already using a tool, they are not actually asking "how to X", but "I'm trying to do X with Y, and have Z problem", which normally should be tagged Y. Unsure who are we supposed to tag the ones that are *tabula rasa* problem statements, through I'm not too preoccupied about those. Do you have example of questions where existing tags aren't appropiated?

Comment: @Braiam, not sure what you mean. I've added a few links to real examples.

Comment: Actually, most of the questions tagged [tag:date] are about date manipulation and not the `date` utility specifically, so I suggest we change the scope of that tag, shall we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the low interest, I've just gone and edited the [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) tag to make it a generic *date* tag as opposed to a `date` utility one (the description there was GNU specific by the way).

Feel free to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I like the generic [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) tag approach. The calendar *date* and the utility `date` have much in common.

This however cannot be said about similar problem with the [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag. Currently it is defined as `time` utility, but people constantly use it together with the [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) tag in the *clock* time meaning:

- [date/time setting does not work after unplugging power adapter or sudden power cut](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218056/date-time-setting-does-not-work-after-unplugging-power-adapter-or-sudden-power-c)
- [Why is the localtime reset to the default timezone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214336/why-is-the-localtime-reset-to-the-default-timezone)
- [set my system date & time via terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205229/set-my-system-date-time-via-terminal)

Perhaps the [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag should be renamed to the [time-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-command) as in the [cd-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd-command) case, and the [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag should be deleted or linked to the [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) tag.

Comment: That's a bit of a separate though related issue. But I'd tend to agree. Now, there is a `time` command, but people tend to use the `time` keyword of their shell instead (not a command). Maybe all of `time`, `date`, `clock` could be merged. Though that would cover quite distant notions.