# Tag cleanup: time vs time-utility

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that we have two "time utility" tags -- [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [time-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-utility). There are 8 questions in [time-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-utility) and 209 in [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time).

The time-utility tag had no wiki, so I just now suggested an edit to make it look the same as time's.

I see there have been recent edits to questions that were tagged `time` that were retagged as `time-utility`.

What do you think about merging the time and time-utility tags? Is this a situation where tag-synonyms would be helpful?

I'm willing to help clean up, I just wanted to head in the "right" direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) is an ambiguous tag. It's used to mean several things, at least:

- The `time` utility and shell builtin. These are sufficiently close to use the same tag: [time-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-utility). Examples: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266705/call-time-with-format-option) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226515/different-times-called-in-similar-environments-in-bash)
- Measuring the execution time of a program. This is often but not always done with the `time` utility (like [parallelism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism) ≠ [gnu-parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel) and [scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) ≠ [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell)). Examples: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255328/dd-process-real-vs-sys-time) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254885/log-of-open-and-close-time-of-a-program)
- Computing, parsing or formatting dates and times. There should be a single tag encompassing dates and times as they make a whole. See also [How about a [date-manipulation] tag or redefine the [date] tag?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/how-about-a-date-manipulation-tag-or-redefine-the-date-tag). Examples: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265950/convert-unix-timestamp-to-hhmmsssss-where-sss-is-milliseconds-in-awk) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237603/unix-epoch-in-milliseconds) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245751/date-getting-next-certain-hour)
- Working with file timestamps. We have [timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timestamps) for that. Example: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255479/incorrect-file-creation-modification-time) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232023/gnu-find-cmatime-option-and-daylight-saving-time)
- What time it is, i.e. reading or setting a clock. That's what [clock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clock) is for. Examples: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259927/must-set-cmos-clock-to-localtime-due-to-dos-dual-boot-timedatectl-or-hwclock) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/what-service-executes-that-sets-up-the-real-time-clock) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255900/system-time-in-minix-with-best-precision)
- Timezone issues, which should be tagged [timezone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timezone). Example: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246553/using-corrected-time-in-the-attribution-variable-of-mutt) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235752/embedded-debian-linux-no-timezone)

While some question touch more than one topic (e.g. display a file's timestamp in a certain format), these are all distinct topics that tags would help sort out, so we should get rid of the ambiguous tags [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) and [time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and use more specific tags instead.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one possibility, just to kick things off:

- Re-tag all 209 'time' questions to 'time-utility' then make time a synonym of time-utility.

Comment: If this does happen, there's an automated system for it, you don't need to start retagging questions one at a time

Comment: Uh.. Why would you retag 209 questions instead of 8? O.o Wouldn't it be better to make the vaguer time a synonym of time-utility?

Comment: @muru that's the direction I was thinking of, but if there were opinions in the other direction, I didn't want to make extra work. I also didn't know if a tag had to be empty of questions before it could be made a synonym.

Comment: A lot of questions currently tagged [tag:time] (a majority, in fact, by my cursory sampling) are not about the `time` utility.